# MVC DisplayTemplate Not Rendering if Named for Interface

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, display-templates

I have a Model:

```
public class Dog: IPet
{
    // IPet Implementation
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and a DisplayTemplate in `DisplayTemplates/Dog.cshtml`

```
@model IPet // note this is the interface, not the concrete Dog
<label>@Model.Name</label>
```

This works perfectly until I rename the file to `IPet.cshtml`; then the binding fails.  I want to use the same DisplayTemplate for `Dog`, `Cat`, `Rat`, `Goat` and `Gnu`, all of which are implementations of `IPet`.

How can I get the binding to work?

Comment: How are you currently invoking the view in your controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the name of the view is the name of an object type that passed to template-helper. So need to explicitly define the template name:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Dog, "IPet")
```

When need to render the model that contains *IPet* instances use [UIHint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.uihintattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)-attribute:

```
public partial class Zoo
{
    [UIHint("IPet")]
    public Dog Dog;

}
```

Template:

```
@model Zoo
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Comment: Is there any way to customize the view creator (whatever that is) to check for the type declared as the `@model` _first_, then fallback to the default method of finding a display template?